# SQL дублирование строк при объединении (JOIN) нескольких таблиц

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

В базе данных есть три таблицы: *words*, *phrases* и *examples*. Первая хранить конкретное слова; вторая - фразы с этим словом; третья - примеры с ним. Две последнии относятся к таблице words как один ко многим: одному слову может соответсвовать множество фраз и/или примеров.

Проблема в том, что при попытке объеденить данные из трех этих таблиц при помощи такого запроса

```
select words.word, examples.eng_example, examples.ru_example, phrases.eng_phrase,  phrases.ru_phrase from words
    inner join examples on examples."wordId" = words.id
        inner join phrases on phrases."wordId" = words.id
```

на выходе получаю такую таблицу с повторяющимеся строками (они выделены желтым):
[image: Таблица, содержащая повторяющиеся данные]

Собственно вопрос: почему так происходит? можно ли получить что-то вроде этого?
[image: Таблица, не содержащая повторяющиехся данных]

И что делать если количество строк из examples не равно количеству строк из phrases?

P.S. Использую SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что используете JOIN правильно? Не лучше ли здесь будет использовать OUTER JOIN? [Гайд по join](https://shra.ru/2017/09/sql-join-v-primerakh-s-opisaniem/)

По второму вопросу, посмотрите функцию sql 'Coalesce'
[Сссылка](https://oracleplsql.ru/coalesce-function.html)

Мне кажется у Вас пропущена связь между "фразами" и "примерами", лучше сделать так:
во фразах foreign key до id слова, а в примерах foreign key до фразы.
Идея в том, чтобы убрать зависимость пример-слово, и перенести ее на таблицу с фразами, хотя на самом деле и это не верно.

Если у Вас подразумевается, что у одного слова есть одна фраза и один пример, сделайте промежуточную таблицу: id | word_id | phrase_id | example_id  и выводите из нее данные через LEFT JOIN заменяя null COALESCE, для этой таблицы пропишите foreign key для word_id с параметром ON DELETE CASCADE.

Удачи.

Comment: За хорошую статью по Join спасибо, хотя она мне и не помогла сделать так, как я хочу, но зато познакомился с ними поближе. В итоге реализовал все через обычный select.

А вот зачем реализовывать связь между "фразами" и "примерами" я не понял. В чем преймущество.

Comment: Преимущество связи "многие ко многим" в том, что она гибкая, а у Вас случай именно с таким "запросом" на гибкость.